# Whats the difference between normal recursive solutions and Dynamic Programming related recursive solutions?

Tags: recursion, data-structures, iteration, dynamic-programming

Can anyone please help me with this , How is the DP's Iterative approach different from the Recursive Approach.

Comment: Don't spam langauge tags.

Comment: DP's Iterative approach is different from the Recursive Approach by the fact that it is **not recursive**.

Comment: Or as [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming/) says it: *Dynamic Programming is **mainly an optimization** over plain recursion. Wherever we see a recursive solution that has **repeated calls for same inputs**, we can optimize it using Dynamic Programming.*

Comment: @Andreas Seems like that could be turned into an answer. At least for me it comes over as an interesting and helpful angle.

Comment: @Andreas--except that recursion is normally used with memorization which makes the two solutions more equivalent in computational complexity.  The difference being recursion is normally top-down while DP is bottom-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Programming and Recursion aren't necessarily opposites. What you're thinking is Memoization vs. Dynamic Programming.

Dynamic Programming is the approach to a problem that reduces duplicate computations as much as possible. This usually means taking a bottom-up approach - i.e. you calculate answers to smaller scale problems first and then use those answers to calculate higher order problems. Iterative approaches are usually used for Dynamic programming since it seems natural (although you can do it recursively too).

Memoization is the top-down approach to a problem and is usually done through recursion because it is more natural. In this case, you start with a higher order problem and make recursive calls for lower order problems in order to solve it.

In both cases you use a data-structure to store values computed so far.